# Google forms custom message after stopping accepting responses

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

Is there a way to programmatically set a custom message after turning off responses? I am using setAcceptingResponses(false) and next time the form is launched I want the custom message to be displayed? The static message will not work.

Answer (score 1):

This is isn't possible yet. Please log an enhancement here to track this - https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/

Comment: Thanks Arun. I am not able to log it in the issue tracker. The "submit issue" button is greyed out. I am unable to submit it. My use case is as following: I have a form which takes student registrations from a specified time upto certain limit. Before the start time, the 'Accepting Responses' is set to false from the form. The message says when the registration opens. I have a script for 'OnSubmit' which turns off 'Accepting Responses' after certain limit is reached. At the same time, I need to display a message guiding them what to do when the registration is full.

Comment: Saw the update of October 8th 013 - new message added to Form.setCustomClosedFormMessage(message) - Thanks to the Apps script team

Comment: Great! You should add this answer and close this so that the right answer bubbles up!

Answer (score 0):

Automated way:
You will need to have add-on in your Google Form (such as formLimiter).
Reference: https://www.howtogeek.com/779382/how-to-close-a-google-form/

Btw, here's the manual way for your reference too:

1. Open your form in Google Forms and go to the Responses tab at the top. Turn off the toggle for Accepting Responses.
   [image]
2. You’ll see a default message that respondents will receive if they access the form. To use your own, just enter it in the box.
   [image]